# can we generate module-info.java file in existing maven project

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, java-11

We have existing java project with java 8 and spring boot. we are migrating to java 11 and as java 9 start using modules-info.java. i am wondering if there are ways to autogenerate modules-info.java based on existing project?

Comment: First why do you like to use modules? Furthermore the question is: If you are in spring boot why do you like to use module ? A spring boot application is in the end a single jar file which can contain only a single `modules-info.java` which means no real benefit ? And no you can not generated a modules-info.java based on your project....

Comment: @khmarbaise at least the last sentence is not correct.

Comment: You can just not use modules. They are not required. Only very large codebases can benefit from them.

Comment: @Holger As you wrote in your answer yourself ...it needs manual corrections which you can only do if you understand the implications of using modules (and how they work) and an automatically generated can never be 100% correct. So do it yourself and learn how it works...instead of using generating tools without understanding it...

Comment: @khmarbaise even when I know what a tool does, there is no reason to do everything manually when a tool can do the job. That’s not different to selecting “New Class” in an IDE and letting it fill in the well-know stub. Yes, I still have to fill in the actual code myself, but why should I repeatedly write the trivial stuff?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [the `jdeps` command](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/jdeps.html) to generate `module-info.java` files.

The syntax is

```
[path to jdk’s bin]jdeps --generate-module-info <path to source> <path to compiled jar>
```

whereas the jar file contains the compiled currently non-modular class files and the source directory is the target for the `module-info.java`.

`jdeps` will analyze the dependencies and assume the name of the jar file (without the `.jar` suffix) as the module name and store a file `<path to source>\<module-name>\module-info.java` which is suitable for a directory layout having module directories inside the source folder rather than a single-module layout.

Of course, this analysis has limitations and subsequent manual corrections might be necessary.

Comment: It also implies having a single modules spring boot app which might be wrong etc.